# How to convert find_element_by_accessibility_id into a case-insensitive function

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests, appium

I'm automating some desktop apps and some applications change their components' ids from lowercase to uppercase and vice-versa very often. The ids are always the same, just the case alternates.

Due to that I get assertion errors.

I am using winappdriver.

```
self.find_element_by_acessibility_id("SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.PCGallery_3c1yjt4zspk6g!App")
```

Ps: The id alternates to `SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.PCGallery_3C1YJT4ZSPK6g!APP`

Comment: Can you show the code that you currently have in place?

Comment: I am using winappdriver.

self.find_element_by_acessibility_id("SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.PCGallery_3c1yjt4zspk6g!App")

Ps: The id alternates to "SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.PCGallery_3C1YJT4ZSPK6g!APP"

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach you can use the **constant** part of the *`accessibility-id`* as follows:

```
self.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@accessibility-id, 'SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO')]")
```

---

### tl; dr

Link to documentations:

- [Appium - Find Element](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-element/)
- [Appium - Find Elements](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/index.html#selector-strategies)

Comment: It doesn't work well, because there are other apps that start with 'SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO'

Answer (score 0):

You can use *matches*. Using the "i" [flag](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#flags), the match operates in case-insensitive mode.

I believe something like this would work:

```
matches(@accessibility-id, 'SAMSUNGELECTRONICSCO.LTD.PCGallery_3c1yjt4zspk6g!App', 'i')
```